# Excel 2016 VBA - status bar not showing complete message

Tags: excel, vba, statusbar

I recently installed the most recent updates to Office 365 on my computer (Windows 10 64-bit).  Since then, I have noticed a strange thing in Excel 2016: the status bar isn't showing the complete custom message I have displaying on it.  It displays it okay when the file first opens, but once a change is made, it won't display the entire message, and instead shows "..." where the last couple of characters should be.  There is still plenty of room on the status bar for the rest of my message, so I can't figure out why this is happening.

I created a new file to see if it was something to do with the specific workbook I was working on.  It did it on the new file as well, so the problem seems to be something to do with Excel itself.  I looked online for a solution, but wasn't able to find anything.  I even posted on a couple of other forums about this, but did not receive an answer, so thought I would try here.  (See the end of my post for the links to those other forum posts.)

Here's a summary of what happens in my test file, as well as a link to the file itself.

When I first open my test file, it shows the status bar message just as it should. [StatusBarPic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/830LU.png)

I made it so the message that would be displayed would change, based on the value in Cell A1. Upon open, Cell A1 is empty.  Then I put a value into it, and the status bar changed just as it should have. [StatusBarPic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2SB8.png)

Then I deleted the value in Cell A1, and the status bar should have returned to looking just as it did when the file was first opened.  However, it didn't.  It wouldn't show the last two characters, and instead showed "..." [StatusBarPic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8dpS.png)

Does anyone have any idea why it is doing this?  It seems bizarre that it would show the message just fine when first opening the workbook, but then not show the exact same message once the file was being used.

Here is the link to download the test file, if you would like to test it yourself.  I would be curious to hear if it does not do this on other versions of Excel.  Maybe this is something new to a recent update of Excel 2016?

[Test Excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/if8693weievd7vw/Test-StatusBarMessage.xlsm?dl=0)

Lastly, here are the posts I made on other forums about this same issue.
[Link to post on Mr. Excel forums](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1072272-max-characters-allowed-statur-bar.html)
[Link to post on VBA Express forums](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?63763-Max-characters-allowed-on-status-bar)

EDIT: Per the request, here is the code I have put into my Test File.

In Sheet1 Module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.StatusBar = MessageToDisplay

End Sub
```

In ThisWorkbook Module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.StatusBar = MessageToDisplay

End Sub
```

In Module1 Module:

```
Function MessageToDisplay() As String

Dim ValueCellA1 As String

ValueCellA1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

MessageToDisplay = "This is a test to see how long of a message can be displayed on the status bar. I have noticed in Excel 2016 (most current version) that there seems to be a limit.  The value of Cell A1 is: " & ValueCellA1

End Function
```

---

In the workbook I am working on, I don't appear to have a blank space at the end of the string I am writing to the status bar, yet I still get the "..." instead of the last two characters of my message.

I stepped through the code and put the string with the message into the watch window. Near the end of the code, I took a screenshot of the watch window.  Here's the very end of the string.
[Watchlist image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/830LU.png)

Yet here is what is displayed on the status bar.
[Status Bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2SB8.png)

In this particular workbook, the user decides what data to display on the status bar by checking some boxes.  Here is the code that determines what actually is displayed on the status bar.  In no instance should the MessageToDisplay string ever have a blank space at the end.

```
    If .Range("Options_StatusBar_ShowTotal1").Value = "YES" Then
        MessageToDisplay = "Total1: " & Total1
        FirstPartWritten = True
    End If

    If .Range("Options_StatusBar_ShowTotal2").Value = "YES" Then
        If FirstPartWritten = False Then
            MessageToDisplay = "Total2: " & Total2
            FirstPartWritten = True
        Else
            MessageToDisplay = MessageToDisplay & "     " & "Total2: " & Total2
        End If
    End If

    If .Range("Options_StatusBar_ShowTotal2Var").Value = "YES" Then
        If FirstPartWritten = False Then
            MessageToDisplay = "Total2 Var: " & Total2Var
            FirstPartWritten = True
        Else
            MessageToDisplay = MessageToDisplay & ", Var: " & Total2Var
        End If
    End If

    If .Range("Options_StatusBar_ShowTotal3").Value = "YES" Then
        If FirstPartWritten = False Then
            MessageToDisplay = "Total3: " & Total3
            FirstPartWritten = True
        Else
            MessageToDisplay = MessageToDisplay & "     Total3: " & Total3
        End If
    End If

    If .Range("Options_StatusBar_ShowTotal3Var").Value = "YES" Then
        If FirstPartWritten = False Then
            MessageToDisplay = "Total3 Var: " & Total3Var
            FirstPartWritten = True
        Else
            MessageToDisplay = MessageToDisplay & ", Var: " & Total3Var
        End If
    End If
```

Also, the message I am trying to display is definitely not over 255 characters.

Comment: I can reproduce this Excel 365. Just to add, if you enter a value in A1 again it will display the complete message. If you delete it again you will get the message with the dots at the end. Interesting, strange but I wouldn't care that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Simply first clearing the status bar solved the issue.

```
Application.StatusBar = "" 
Application.StatusBar = msg
```

Comment: Just tried this, and it does seem to work for me.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the behavior described above has to do if there are blank spaces at the end of the text.
I was able to fix it in the following way

```
Function MessageToDisplay() As String

Dim ValueCellA1 As String

    ValueCellA1 = WorksheetFunction.Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("A1").Value)
    If Len(ValueCellA1) = 0 Then
        MessageToDisplay = "This is a test to see how long of a message can be displayed on the status bar. I have noticed in Excel 2016 (most current version) that there seems to be a limit.  The value of Cell A1 is:"
    Else
        MessageToDisplay = "This is a test to see how long of a message can be displayed on the status bar. I have noticed in Excel 2016 (most current version) that there seems to be a limit.  The value of Cell A1 is: " & ValueCellA1
    End If

End Function
```

I also got the dots displaying when using `Application.StatusBar = "Test "`. It seems you have to make sure that you do not have any blanks at the end of the text you want to display.

**Update** I think the max length of the text for the status bar is 255

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try this.  Unfortunately, in the actual workbook I am creating, I don't seem to have a blank space at the end of the string I am trying to display, yet I am still getting the three dots before the end of my message.  I will create an answer to give more details.